# Ajax call working on localhost but does not on azure-webites.net

Tags: azure-web-app-service

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function validemail(isemail) {
            var emailReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            return emailReg.test(isemail);
        }

        $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").blur(function () {            
            if ($("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").siblings().size() > 0) {
                $("div").remove(".tooltips");
            }
        });


        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var name = $("#<%=txtName.ClientID %>").val();
            var email = $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").val();
            var message = $("#<%=txtMessage.ClientID %>").val();
            if (name != '' && email != '' && message != '') {
                if (validemail(email)) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "http://abcname.azurewebsites.net/Contact.aspx/InsertData",
                        data: "{'customername':'" + name + "','customeremail':'" + email + "','customermessage':'" + message + "'}",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            var obj = data.d;
                            if (obj == 'true') {
                                $("#<%=txtName.ClientID %>").val('');
                                $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").val('');
                                $("#<%=txtMessage.ClientID %>").val('');
                                alert('Details submitted successfully');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("An error occur while submitting details.");
                        }
                    });
                }

                else {
                    $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").focus();
                    $("<div class='tooltips'><span>Invalid Email Address</span></div>").insertAfter("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>");
                }
            }
            else {
                alert('Please fill all the fields');              
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Above code perfectly working on local host but it doesn't on server side. If there would any error on the .cs file then it will show alert box, but it even doesn't showing alert box that "An error occur while submitting details"

Comment: perhaps [cors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) is the culprit?

Comment: could you please elaborate it. How can i resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

> url: "http://abcname.azurewebsites.net/Contact.aspx/InsertData",

Based on the URL, I suspected that you were using WebMethod to handle AJAX request in WebForms application. Since there were .aspx suffix in your URL, please make sure you have commented out the following code which default exist in RouteConfig.cs.

```
//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
```

> but it even doesn't showing alert box that "An error occur while submitting details"
>
> var obj = data.d;

The reason for this may be that the response is came back but it doesn’t contain a property named d or its value doesn’t equals ‘true’. I suggest use a tool to view the detail response message. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is common tool which could help you do it.

In addition, did you send the AJAX request from different domain as 'http://**abcname**.azurewebsites.net'? For example,  the code which you posted is in the website named 'http://**defname**.azurewebsites.net'. If it is true, you need to configure CORS in abcname web app. Steps below are for your reference.

1. In Azure portal, open web app abcname.
2. On menus bar, click CORS.
3. Input the domain name in the ‘Allowed Regions’ textboxes.
4. Click [Save] button to save all your operations.

[image]